# Find a solution $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ of this system such that $X_3 = 24.$

Tags: linear-algebra

A system of three linear equations with four unknowns X1, X2, X3, X4 has two solutions

$(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) = (2,3,4,5)$
and
$(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) = (7,8,9,10)$

Find a solution $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ of this system such that $X_3 = 24.$

Edit:
Hello everyone, I m new to the community and just learned that I'am not supposed to just post a problem.

This seems to be something that I should figure out quickly but Im just not able to.
I do not know how to work with a linear system where I do not have a constant on the other side of the equivalency.
I have tried to put the set of solutions in a matrix form with some unknowns but it led me nowhere.
I really have no idea on how to approach the problem.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: $(X_1,X_2,X_3,24)=(2,3,4,5)$ seems wrong. $24=5?$

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant to put X4

Comment: I have edited the post to fix a typo and state how I tried to handle the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If $A x = b $ has a solution $x_1$ and a solution $x_2$ , then let

$x_3 = (1 - \lambda) x_1 + \lambda x_2 $

Once can see that $x_3$ is also a solution.

Therefore,

$x_3 = (X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) =  (1 - \lambda) (2,3,4,5) + \lambda (7,8,9,10) $

is a solution.  Now it is required that $X_3 = 24 $, therefore,

$ 4 (1 - \lambda) + 9 \lambda = 24 $

From which, $5 \lambda + 4 = 24 $

which implies $\lambda = 4 $

Hence, the solution is

$ (1 - 4) (2, 3, 4, 5) + 4 (7, 8, 9, 10) = ( 22 , 23 , 24 , 25 ) $

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Would you please tell me how you came up with the expression: 3=(1−)1+2.
Is it a property?

Comment: If A x = b is a linear system, and $u$ and $v$ are solutions, i.e. $A u = b$ and $A v = b $ then $ A ((1 - \lambda) u + \lambda v ) = (1 - \lambda) b + \lambda b = b $, so $w = (1 - \lambda) u + \lambda v $ is also solution because it satisfies $A w = b $

Answer (score 1):

Since,
$A(2, 3,4,5) =A(7, 8,9,10) $
$A(7-2, 8-3, 9-4, 10-5) =(0, 0,0,0)$

$A(5, 5,5,5) =(0, 0,0,0)$

$A(20, 20,20,20) =(0, 0,0,0)$

$A(20+2, 20+3, 20+4, 20+5) $=$A(2, 3,4,5) $

Hence, Another solution is $(22, 23,24,25)$ having $X_3=24$
We easily show using linearity property of Matrix.